# Encrypting data in POST

Tags: javascript, perl, post, encryption, cgi

I want to create a authentication mechanism in which the client side is JavaScript and it fetches the password and username from the client and post it to the CGI Perl script.

The problem is that the username and password is free text. I want to make it encrypted or hashed but at the CGI I want to check it so I need the password again.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to re-invent the wheel. Use a HTTPS connection for that. It automatically does everything you need to safeguard your information.

Comment: How is the password being stored server side? MD5, SHA1?

Comment: in server side for uptil now the password is in text format so in the end on server side i am matching with text

Comment: @mohkhan how to make https connection since i have made the post with http can you guide me i am new .

Comment: @user1995749: Take a look at Authen::Passphrase, for ways to encrypt server-side (assuming you don't have a *need* to store plaintext passwords). I'd also recommend Michael's answer of using https for handling client-server communications. http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Authen-Passphrase-0.008/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using an https connection. This solves your problem with having to encrypt/decrypt data yourself (but instead requires some effort to set up).

Comment: kindly provide me the link to create the connection on https.

Comment: Https ensures secure transmission, but password encryption has to be done either way, be it on the client or on the server. So it would be an additional layer for security, which the TO should use.

Comment: You do not have to use encryption to authenticate a user. You should persist salted hashed passwords and compare those to the provided password. I am certain you can find plenty of code examples (e.g. on http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used the term "encryption" wrong. What I ment was "hashed".

Answer (score 3):

This is in response to comments suggesting client-side encryption, not HTTPS.

---

It is important to consider what you are protecting from whom.

#### Server side

Server side hashing is important to buy time should the database be compromised.

From the view of the server/the CGI script, you receive some form of authentication token, which you want to validate.

Comparing the token with stored plaintext is dangerous, if somebody else can access the plaintext database. This is insecure if somebody else has physical access to the server, access to backups, or can run software on the server. Even then, faulty configuration or unknown exploits could expose the plaintext passwords.

Therefore, some kind of (non-reversible) hashing *has* to occur on the server side. MD5 is not a viable solution. Actually, no “fast” hashes (incl. the SHA algorithms) provide good protection any more: they are opimized for fast and secure integrity validation, not for making password cracking as difficult as possible. This can be mitigated by repeated hashing/key stretching (see [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking#Prevention)). It is also important to include random “salt”. Do not consider “optimizing” here.

#### Transportation

Transportation encryption protects against snoopers.

The secret access token has to be transferred securely from the client to the server. This is usually done via HTTPS.

If the password is hashed in the client, the hashed access token effectively becomes the secret that has to be protected. Visualization:

```
      CLIENT       | TRANSPORT  | SERVER
                   |            |
password => HaShEd | >>>>>>>>>> | verification that “HaShEd” is valid.
                             ^  | never sees “password”.
  snooper can see “HaShEd”   |  |
  can make malicious request |>>|
```

This is no different from an unencrypted password. Therefore, any pre-hashed access token has to be encrypted during transport, e.g. via HTTPS. If you use reversible encryption for the password, you have to securely transmit encryption keys. This is a solved problem with asymetric encryption, but if you just use HTTPS you don't have to think about all of this, it happens automatically.

#### Client-Side encryption

Encrypting on the client side is only sensible when you want to protect a secret from the server. A use case for this is uploading confidential files to a server. If they are encrypted on the client side, the server can be compromised without having the files compromised. For authentication, this **does not provide any useful functionality**.

All it can do is to lull the user in a false sense of security. The actual secret is just different from the access token the user knows.

---

Beyond passwords, password-less authentication schemes can be used. The most important of these is OpenID (as used with stackoverflow), where you trust a third party identity provider (e.g. Google, Facebook, GitHub) to authenticate the user. You never see the secret, but only get a yes/no message from the identity provider.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps that would be what you are looking for: [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)
So you could encrypt your data clientside and do the authentication serverside.

Comment: if the data is encrypted on the client side then the when the parameters are received by the cgi is also encrypted so how to decrypt the encryption provided by the javascript and decrypt at perl

Comment: Why decrypt it at all? The way to go would be to store the data encrypted and to compare with the encrypted values, not the clear value. E.g. Username 3248u23sd9dsa4das7d2ff8f9374234 has not to match "John Doe" in the database, but 3248u23sd9dsa4das7d2ff8f9374234 or perhaps you do further encryption on the serverside if you are paranoid.

Comment: if we are doing the procedure as mentioned by you the procedure is that first suppose the password is kh123 i take the encryption of the password with key suppose 123 at javascript client and then store the value in db and then when user comes it will again do encryption of the password and send if the encrypted value is same as of the previous it sends ack ....
since i am new ... is it the procedure or there may be improvement

Comment: I think that is the way to go. Whether you are doing the encryption serverside or clientside is up to you, but you have to store an encrypted version in your database not the clear one, And why would you want to decrypt a user's password anyways?

Comment: it was actually a lack of expertise i think making the solution more complex for myself :) thanks alot all